# Email в интернет с  Open Server или Denwer

Tags: email, сервер

Можно ли как-то отправить письмо с Openserver или Denwer используя ф-ию mail()?

Comment: @ХэшКод Хорошо. В будущем учту:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привет!
Вам надо поставить mail сервер (например sendmail (в Denwer стоит заглушка)), затем в файле php.ini прописать соот. настройки [mail]

Comment: а что за настройки. Можно подробнее, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2):

Вы заглядывали в настройки OpenServer? Там закладка "Почта", выбираете или складировать в локальную папку, или отправлять через удаленный SMTP сервер. И Mail servser ставить не надо. Да и вообще, мануал на русском языке, где всё подробно описано. К тому же, [форум есть](http://open-server.ru/forum/).  А про Денвер пора забыть. Уже больше года наблюдаю:

```
Регистрация требуется в связи с будущим выходом Денвера-4.
```

Проект заглох, а OpenServer регулярно обновляется (последний раз - 19 августа 2012), не такой глючный, настроек и возможностей на хороший порядок выше.

Comment: во-во. опенсервер поинтереснее штука, но на unix машине все гораздо приятнее настраивать.

Comment: Я это знаю. Но мне не нужен удаленный сервер. Я хочу, чтобы все у меня на компе было настроено

Comment: @inferus-vv, раз надо, то [действуйте в направлении](http://forum.dklab.ru/denwer/advises/ReplacementZaglushkiSendmailOnPresentSendmail.html), которое вам предложил ghost rider.

Comment: спасибо) действую