# Как настроить open server для mail()?

Tags: php, openserver

Помогите настроить open server для отправки mail

Comment: открыть 25 порт, либо заюзать php скрипт в php.ini в место sendmail

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/139855/email-в-интернет-с-open-server-или-denwer?rq=1
Попробуйте данный вариант настройки